# Why do SELECT statements only sometimes return results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's example code I'm using:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table #t1

create table #t1 (ID int, name varchar(10))

insert into #t1 values (1,'2'), (6,'2'), (6,'2'), (1,'4')

DECLARE @CHARS VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT @CHARS = @CHARS + name + ', ' 
FROM #t1

SELECT @CHARS -- <---CODE OF INTEREST
```

This returns `2, 2, 2, 4,`.

My Question: why do I have to specify `SELECT @chars` to get my results? Why doesn't my previous `select` statement return the results? I would like an answer to when and why a `select` statement will return results and when it will not.

Comment: In SQL Server, `SELECT` either returns a result set *or* it assigns variables.  A single `SELECT` cannot do both.

Comment: You are using `SELECT` to set a variable, not return a result set.  In this case, it's done recursively.

Comment: Ah I gotcha... I just tried to pull in ID in the same select statement and got the error `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data retrieval operations`. Makes sense!